# nested for loop logic is going wrong

Tags: jquery

I have got quantity of 4 , but when i am executing it is creating 8 lines of code .

Please see this is my code

```
 var addonsQtyWrap = $('<div class="addonsQtyWrap"></div>');

 var json = [{
     "name": "826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab1_checkbox",
         "cost": 100,
         "additionname": "Choco chips",
         "addtionid": 59
 }, {
     "name": "826_ZZ_0_ZZ_0tab2_checkbox",
         "cost": 100,
         "additionname": "Choco chips",
         "addtionid": 59
 }];

 var quantity = 4;
 var ulhtml = '<ul>';


 for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {

     for (var k = 0; k < json.length; k++) {

         var name = json[k].name;

         var res = name.indexOf("tab" + (k + 1));

         if (res !== -1) {
             ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik active">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
         } else {
             ulhtml += '<li    data-tabid="' + i + '"   class="tabclcik">Qty-' + i + '</li>';
         }

     }
 }
 addonsQtyWrap.append(ulhtml);
 $("#header").append(addonsQtyWrap);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/29/

please let me know whats the issue . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Its working as per design `4 * 2(json.length) = 8`

Comment: According to your logic, you getting the correct result, but what you want ?
Is you want ?
Qty-0
Qty-1
Qty-2
Qty-3

Comment: Please let me first whats your requirement ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cod7ceho/31/ ?

Comment: I am checking for the corresponding tab in the json array if it has got i need to add class active to the corresponding quantity while creating that  . this is my requirement .

Comment: the json array has got name such as tab1_checkbox , tab2_checkbox , so i want to add class active to the quantity 1 and quantity 2 respectively ,this is i am trying.

Comment: @ArunPJohny , still it is creating 8 quantities know ,

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/umesh195sehta/rjhoobj5/

Comment: If you want tab according to json result then why are you assigning static value to quantity.

Comment: But if i do so , i am missing 2  quanities to be created .

Comment: The  quantity and the json array length are not same , and they will vary .

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 loops:

```
//4 loops
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

 //inside each loop this will run 2 times
 for (var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
```

If you want 4 lines you will need to change the `quantity` to `2` or change the logic of your code.